# Python - failing to update 90% of rows

Tags: python, mysql

```
cur.execute("""SELECT match_own_goals.game_id, home_team, away_team, team, time 
                 FROM football.match_own_goals 
                 JOIN football.match_info 
                 ON match_own_goals.game_id = match_info.game_id""")
e = cur.fetchall()

for game in e:
    print game
    time = game[4]
    print type(time)
    if game[3] == 1:
        team_id = game[1]
    else:
        team_id = game[2]
    cur.execute("""UPDATE football.match_own_goals 
                   SET team_id = %s 
                   WHERE time = %s AND game_id = %s""", (team_id, time, game[0]))
db.commit()
```

This has updated about 10% of the rows, no idea why.  time is actually a float (it doesn't represent a time, more a point in time during a football match e.g. 87mins, 54mins).

Time is definately the problem as when I removed it it worked fine, but I really need it in there for other tables.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: You got or its bug in your code `%` missing in UPDATE query. `WHERE time = %s AND game_id = %s""" % (team_id, time, game[0]))`

Comment: What you are doing wrong is comparing a float using `=`.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: thanks for your comment. That is not a bug in the code, but rather how the DB-API specifies that queries should be run.

Comment: to emphasize, you should absolutely **never** use the `%` operator in `cursor.execute()`.  (perhaps use `oursql`, which uses `?` for placeholders like everything else instead of `%s`  :))

Answer (score 1):

`time = %s` this is definitely an issue (you can not properly compare floats with equation operator, read more about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-float.html)).